# API MANAGER 3.0 - API PUBLISHER NOT LOADING

Tags: wso2

I am doing a **POC** with my team as we are introducing **WSO2** components and am working with the **API Manager 3.0**.

I seem to be having issues loading the **WSO2 API Manager** / **API Publisher** on the defined URL;

```
https://[ip address]/publisher
```

The page is not loading and I keep getting a spinning circle.

Steps I have taken:

1. Stop **API Manager** at command prompt with `[Ctrl + C]` command
2. Modified `deployment.toml` file specified paths for the localhost to our IP Address, API [publisher, gateway and store] URL values to use our IP Address as well.
3. Changed `carbon.xml` and `api_manager.xml`
4. Start **API Manager** with `wso2server.bat --run` command

Issues are as follows;

1. `api_manager.xml` values are reset to `localhost` and not the IP Address I modified it to.
2. The **API Publisher** page is not loading and I am not able to get to the **API Publisher** login page.

I am an administrator on the Windows Server hosting this, so all changes are made as admin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, APIM 3.0 has a [new config model](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Reference/ConfigCatalog/), where all configurations are available (only) in `deployment.toml`. All other configurations are populated based on that, and shouldn't be changed manually.

Second, you don't need to replace all occurrences of `localhost` to IP as many are local calls.

Third, the correct URL should have the port, unless you have a reverse proxy in front of API.

`eg. https://[ip address]:9443/publisher`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good and thanks for the input. I will give this a try and post back to the thread.

I am using the IP and Port for now with no reverse proxy but plan to add one, once I can get through this part.

Much appreciated.